# xsl - Get all attributes from childs

Tags: xslt, attributes

I'm having some trouble getting all the attributes from the parent tag, and their childs.
This is my the XML:

```
<macro name="editor">
        <names variable="editor" delimiter=", ">
            <name and="symbol" delimiter=", "/>
            <label form="short" prefix=" (" text-case="lowercase" suffix=".)" />
       </names>
</macro>
```

I want to be able to get the  and all the attributes from the childnodes.
I currently have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="macro">
   <xsl:value-of select="@*" />
   <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

How I want it to turn out:

**editor**

names editor,

name symbol,

label short ( lowercase .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When this XSLT transformation**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="macro">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@*" separator=""/>

    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@*" separator=""/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**runs on below XML:**

```
<macro name="editor">
        <names variable="editor" delimiter=", ">
            <name and="symbol" delimiter=", "/>
            <label form="short" prefix=" (" text-case="lowercase" suffix=".)" />
       </names>
</macro>
```

**gives the required output:**

```
editor
names editor, 
name symbol, 
label short (lowercase.)
```

Comment: Hey, this all looks great. One question though, what does "child::*" do exactly? Never use that. Im currently getting the following: "editor names editor name symbol label short"

Comment: @ErikÅstrand: child::* will matches any child element of the current node.

Comment: @ErikÅstrand: If this is correct answer, could you please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all varibale name and value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="macro">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*//@*">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' : ', .)"/>
      <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
variable : editor
    delimiter : , 
    and : symbol
    delimiter : , 
    form : short
    prefix :  (
    text-case : lowercase
    suffix : .)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="print_attr">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="print_attr">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_attr" select="@*|*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="macro">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_attr" select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate this output:

```
editor
<br/>names editor,
<br/>name symbol,
<br/>label short (lowercase.)
```